# data not get in proper manner which i want in postgresql multiple inner join

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, join, inner-join

i.m trying to do a inner join on two table. 1. users , 2. rides. in user table there are two types of user(0 for user , 1 for driver). and in ride table i store user_id and provide_id which came from users table. so now problem is that i can't get information of both user simultaneously.

```
SELECT name,mobile, email, name as driverName
FROM users 
INNER JOIN rides  
ON users._id  = rides.user_id
INNER JOIN rides as ride 
ON users._id  = ride.provider_id;
```

this return me null table.

| name | number | email | drivername |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

and when i use only single join :

````
SELECT name,mobile, email, name as driverName
FROM users 
INNER JOIN rides  
ON users._id  = rides.user_id```

 it return me name , mobile and email but not drivername.

| name | number | email |drivername |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|----------:|
| xyz  | 000000 | email |           |

i want ouput like this

| name | number | email |drivername |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|----------:|
| xyz  | 000000 | email |  abcsd    |
````

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to express your query using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT u.name, u.mobile, u.email
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rides r WHERE u._id = r.user_id) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rides r WHERE u._id = r.provider_id);
```

This will return every user for whom there is a both a user and provider ride.

Comment: soory but it is also return me a null table. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: ...then no users are both passengers and drivers.  In this case, what output do you want to display?  Do you always want to report every user, even when there are no matches?